# Aligning data in a table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, word-wrap

In the following table, how do I align the data in `td` cells such that we do not get a horizontal scroll bar, using CSS?

Also the requirement is that the height of the table should be adjusted automatically..

```
<table> 
   <tr><th>name</th>
   <th>info</th></tr>
   <tr><td>Harry</td>
     <td>suminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosum infosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfos uminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfo<td></tr>
   <tr><td>test</td><td>test data</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To support all browser go for this

```
.workbreak {
      word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
      white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
      white-space: pre-wrap;      /* current browsers */
}

<table> 
   <tr><th>name</th>
   <th>info</th></tr>
   <tr><td>Harry</td>
     <td class="workbreak">suminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfosuminfo<td></tr>
   <tr><td>test</td><td>test data</td></tr>
</table>
```

For more detail : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space

Comment: yes its not supported in Mozila to work with it try white-space: pre-wrap in FF

Comment: it should be word-wrap and this will only work with css3 capable browsers

Comment: @corroded :- & which are css3 capable browsers?

Comment: see the link in answer according to it style sheet must work in mozila

Answer (score 0):

The extra long cell needs `word-wrap:break-word`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  width: 600px; /* or whatever you like */
}
```